# Cannot find segue with identifier

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, segue

I have the following code:

In 1 class (GamePlay1) I have method that change view controller if game ends:

```
 -(void)end
 {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"menu1" sender:self];
 }
```

In 2 SKView class i have a method that calls function in 1 class to change view controller:

```
 -(void)gameEnded
 {
     GamePlay1 *gp1 = [[GamePlay1 alloc]init];
     [gp1 end];
 }
```

I get the warning:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<GamePlay1: 0x156329e0>) has no segue with identifier 'menu1''
```

I tried to change seque name for few times, also I tried to clean my project, deleting app and installing again, but the result is the same.

Comment: The segue identifier from the error is named "menu1" in one case and "menu" in your code.

Comment: Mistake while writing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segue is defined in a storyboard, when instantiating the class manually with alloc and init, the controller has no reference to the IB object, therefore no segue is defined. You want to use the storyboard itself to instantiate your controller:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
GamePlay1 *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GamePlay1"];
[controller end];
```

Please note that this is not the proper way of doing a segue, you need to obtain a reference to the current instantiated viewcontroller instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Okay i understand the first part! But can you explain me the part of doing a segue properly? tnx!

Comment: For what I understand, when you are performing the `end` segue your current visible view controller is a `GamePlay1` controller. If that's the case, you don't need to instantiate a new controller of that kind, but you can call performSegue on its current instance. You can for example use delegation: your view will call a method on its delegate (the GamePlay1 instance) that will perform the segue. Remember that views should never hold data, and therefore should never instantiate new viewcontrollers. They need to be "stupid" and comunicate with controllers with delegation, kvo or notifications

Comment: Looks like I ran out of space in the comment. My suggestion would be to spend some time learning the foundamental patterns of cocoa. A good resource to do so is the Stanford course that you find for free on [iTunes U](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550)